# No toString method

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I found in the codebase an if statement which part of it is redundant.

```
if(undefined === value || null === value || !value.toString)
```

Is there something in js that doesn't have `toString` defined (apart from `undefined` and `null`)?

Comment: I don't know of anything that doesn't have a `toString` method (`Object.prototype` does), but I could easily make something. Say, `{toString:null}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objective of that code is to check if the value variable has the toString method defined then it is strange, as the only case that would evaluate to false is if value is undefined.

I took the liberty to create a fiddle for you (http://jsfiddle.net/gnrcc/2/) with the following code:

```
var obj = new String("Hi, im an object"); // String object
var str = "Hello, im a primitive" // string primitive
var und; // undefined

// will output native method, string and object details
console.log(obj.toString, obj.toString(), obj); 
// will output native method, string and string
console.log(str.toString, str.toString(), str);  
// will get property undefined error
console.log(und.toString, und.toString(), und);
```

- All Objects have the toString method (from the Object prototype)
- All Primitives will get automatically wrapped by theyr corresponding Object when a method is called on them, resulting in the same behaviour as Objects (Edit: the exception is obviously the undefined primitive)